# How do I create a view different than the model with Django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, I have this 2 classes of servers and datacenters;

```
 class Datacenter(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

 class Servers(models.Model):

    datacenter = models.ForeignKey(Datacenter)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

And want to create a view that returns the details of the datacenter plus all the servers that are related, so right now when I do;

http://127.0.0.1:8000/datacenter/1/

I'm getting something like;

```
 {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "TestDC"
 }
```

But what I'm actually looking to get is something like this;

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "TestDC",
"Servers": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "hostname": "Server1",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "hostname": "Server2",
    }
  ]
}
```

Right now my view is this;

```
 class DatacenterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

     queryset = datacenter.objects.all()
     serializer_class = datacenterSerializer
```

and my serialiazer;

```
 class DatacenterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = Datacenter
         fields = ('id','name')
```

I also would like to have that server list in an other method like;

http://127.0.0.1:8000/datacenter/1/Servers

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

**Nested Servers:**

If you want (almost) exactly the output you gave as a sample, then it would be this:

```
class ServersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Servers
        fields = ('id', 'hostname')

class DatacenterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    servers = ServersSerializer(source='servers_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Datacenter
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

If you want to show all fields for both models, then just drop the 'fields' line.

This could also work without the source keyword argument, but would require the related name to match the 'servers' property name (you could do this by adding related_name='servers' to the datacenter field on the Servers model).

The docs for DRF are pretty good, the bits you care about are [serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)

**Deep URL:**

To achieve the nested URL structure, you could simply make an url pattern that matches the above like so:

```
url(r'^datacenter/(?P<datacenter_id>\d+)/Servers$', 'views.dc_servers',name="dc_servers")
```

which would call your view with the ID of the Datacenter as the kwarg `datacenter_id`. You would then use that ID to filter the queryset of your view by datacenter_id.

You'll have to look into how to write that view yourself, here are the [views docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) to get you started.

A couple of  general Django tips: Models should usually have singular names rather than plural and adding a related_name argument is usually a good thing (explicit over implicit).

Answer (score 1):

To show the Servers you can do this on the serializer:

```
class DatacenterSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer): 

    servers = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True
    )
    class Meta: 
        model = Datacenter 
        fields = ('id','name', 'servers')
```

If you want to show several fields of the servers, you should create a ServerSerializer with the fields that you want to show and then replace the line:

```
    servers = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True
    )
```

With:

```
    servers = ServerSerializer(many=True)
```

For further information have a look at the doc: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Answer (score 1):

Thanks you both for your answers, finally all I had to do was add the related_name in the model, now it looks like this;

```
class Datacenter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Servers(models.Model):
    datacenter = models.ForeignKey(Datacenter,related_name="servers")
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

---

Regarding the deep URL, I was checking the documentation and it should be possible to accomplish using a SimpleRouter, but couldn't find any example to see how to implement it; {prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}/

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/