# Clean way to implement views or methods with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement some particular views to my ViewSet but keeping a clean and elegant code. I have some servers and some datacenters;

**models.py**

```
class Datacenter(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Server(models.Model):

    datacenter = models.ForeignKey(Datacenter,related_name="servers")
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.hostname
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ServerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Server

class DatacenterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    Servers = ServerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Datacenter
        fields = ('id', 'name','status','Servers')
```

**views.py**

```
class DatacenterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Datacenter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DatacenterSerializer

class ServerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Enviroment', views.EnviromentViewSet)
router.register(r'Server', views.ServerViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^', include(router.urls)))
```

So a clear sample of what I would like to implement is a view of all the servers in one datacenter like;

**/datacenter/{id}/servers**

I check other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969798/adding-more-views-to-a-router-or-viewset-django-rest-framework) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921021/django-rest-framework-detail-page-of-detail-route) but I'm not sure those are actually the best ways, also I was unable to make it work as described in the [answer given by mariodev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18970651/3216056)

I'm trying to avoid to solve this using url patterns like [Tom Dickin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28287971/1018173)

As far as I understand this can be solved using [viewsets](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/), [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) or [generic-views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/)

**Whats the simplest solution? Could someone point me into the right direction?**

Comment: Well you can use ad-hoc methods in viewsets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ad-hoc method

**serializers.py**

```
class ServerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Server

class DatacenterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    servers = ServerSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Datacenter
        fields = ('id', 'name','status','servers')
```

**views.py**

```
class DatacenterViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Datacenter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DatacenterSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get'], permission_classes=[permissions.IsAdminUser])
    def servers(self, request, pk=None):
        servers = Server.objects.filter(datacenter__id=pk)
        serializer = ServerSerializer(servers, many=True, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Enviroment', views.EnviromentViewSet)
router.register(r'server', views.ServerViewSet)
router.register(r'datacenter', views.DatacenterViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'^', include(router.urls)))
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting;

<server: test.server > is not JSON serializable

Comment: @MarceloGrebois please try again with my updated code

Comment: In case I am implementing both a get and a post using an ad-hoc method, how can I differentiate the two - both get routed to the same function right?
Will it be an if/else on request.METHOD